# Shared mutex in C error in Init

Tags: c, mutex, shared-memory

I am trying to make a program with shared memory and execute more than 1 time the same program to increase a value, all this using one shared mutex.

The problem is that in my second execution, the funcion `mutex_init` fail.

any ideas?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define SM_SIZE sizeof (struct shared)
#define min 4
#define max 10

struct shared
{
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    int i;

};

char *shared1_name="asdf";


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

int id_sharedMem1;
int i,j,loops;
struct shared *memoriaC;

loops = atoi(argv[1]);

id_sharedMem1 = shm_open ( shared1_name , O_RDWR, 644 );    

if(id_sharedMem1==-1)
    {    
    id_sharedMem1 = shm_open ( shared1_name , O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 644 );
    if ( id_sharedMem1 == -1 || ftruncate ( id_sharedMem1, SM_SIZE ) == -1) 
        {
        printf("open %s\n",strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
        }

    memoriaC = mmap ( NULL, SM_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, id_sharedMem1, 0 );
    if ( memoriaC == (void *) -1)
        {
        perror ( "mmap" );
        exit(1);
        }
    memoriaC->i=0;
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&(memoriaC->mutex), NULL)!=0)
            printf("mutex init 1 %s\n",strerror(errno));

    }else
        {

        if (pthread_mutex_init(&(memoriaC->mutex), NULL)!=0)
                printf("mutex init 2 %s\n",strerror(errno));

        }

    if(pthread_mutex_lock ( &(memoriaC->mutex))!=0)
            printf("mutex lock %s\n",strerror(errno));

    i = memoriaC->i + 1;
    memoriaC->i = i+loops;
    close ( id_sharedMem1 );
    for(j=0;j<loops;j++)
        i++;

    printf("i= %d\n",i);

    if(pthread_mutex_unlock ( &(memoriaC->mutex))!=0)
        printf("mutex unlock %s\n",strerror(errno));


//shm_unlink ( shared1_name );                      
}
```

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  it is missing the header for the pthread functions.   function ftruncate() has implicit declaration.  ?? function close has implicit declaration??  The parameter 'argc' not used.   BTW:  should always check the value of argc before referencing any command line parameters.  This check is also a good time to output a 'usage' message if not the required number of command line parameters

Comment: I made an adaptation of the code smaller to put it here, I forgot those headers. Run in with sudo and put -lrt in the compilation. The code compiles perfectly even without those 2 headers.

Comment: posted code missing #include <unistd.h>  (for linux, may be different for other OSs.).   posted code missing #include <pthread.h>

Comment: No, the code does NOT compile 'perfectly'  Suggest compiling with all warnings enabled.  (for gcc, at a minimum, use: '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic' )  Then fix the warnings.

Comment: 'min' is defined but not used.   'max' is defined but not used

Comment: what did not you understand about it was a fast implementation? I suggest you to read again which one was my problem and if you want to answer, asnwer something usefull please, because solving thoses warnings I fix nothing.

Comment: these are comments, NOT answers,  See below for any answers.   When posting 'running' (sic) code the requirement is 1) compiles,  2) short, and 3) displays the problem.   Comments are a way to suggest improvements to the code and/or to request clarifications.   Answers are a way to suggest what is basically wrong with the code and how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There a couple "tricks" required to get shared-memory mutexes right:

1) You **must** guarantee only one process / thread creates / initializes the mutex.  You can improve chances of getting this right if you use `O_EXCL` when creating the shared memory, then make the process that succeeds in creating the shared memory responsible for initializing the mutex. This may or may not be a sufficient strategy in itself.

2) You **must** enable sharing the mutex using pthread_mutexattr_setpshared` and related functions.  It is not sufficient to place the mutex in shared memory.

3) You **should** also understand `pthread_mutexattr_settype` and know when and why to use the different types.

4) You **should** use `pthread_mutexattr_setrobust` appropriately, provided your OS supports it.  Otherwise you get  a deadlock if a process exits while holding the lock.

Comment: Naturally, the mutex should NOT be within the shared memory, as the shared memory is the resource being protected by the mutex.

Comment: How exactly is a mutex that is NOT shared between two processes going to protect the shared memory?